# Mail merge displaying wrong numeric data

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, ms-office, export-to-excel, mailmerge

I am using Office 2003

On Access, I export values from a form into a .xls, after that using mail merge on word I import the data to be displayed on the file. Data such as dates and strings are displayed correctly. 
In Access theres the value 9,916.12  wich is exported to the .xls as 'price' that contains 9,916.12, both values match keeping the same format, but when mail merge kicks in the value displayed on the document becomes 9916,1200000000008.

I am lost as to what is causing that. The field that is being exported contains only 2 decimals, it displays on excel as a value with only 2 decimals yet when word reads it, it adds random decimals to it. If I manually alter the value on excel the error persists, so does it if I choose a different record to be exported.

Any tips on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [Microsoft Answers discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/why-is-words-mail-merge-changing-the-value-of/106f5cf9-1975-47d6-a3e9-f6456b7fae31) and this [in-depth description](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/answer-box-numbers-don-t-merge-right-in-word-HA001116495.aspx) on how to use a merge field such as `{Mergefield NumberFieldName \# ",0.00"}` to work around the issue.  It's been awhile since I had to do mail merges, especially with Word 2003, but I think that should do it.

Comment: Thank you, using Dynamic Data Exchange as it says on the Microsoft Answers discussion worked!